# VueJS async detect language with Yandex Translate API

Tags: vue.js, yandex-api

I'm experimenting with Yandex Translate API using VueJS to detect the language of the entered text asynchronously.

Everything works right. But there is a problem; log returns for each letter I write.

For example, when I write 'hello': api predicts the language of each of the words 'h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello' and turns 5 log. What I want is that the API returns 1 log for the word 'hello' asynchronously after the timeout. It checks it for every letter. How can I fix it?

Html part of TranslateForm.vue

```
<template>
    <textarea v-model="translateText" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Translate something."></textarea>
</template>
```

Script part of TranslateForm.vue

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'TranslateForm',
  data () {
    return {
      translateText: '',
      apiKey: '********',
      detectLangApiUrl: '***********'
    }
  },
  watch: {
      translateText (value) {
        if (value) {
          axios.post(this.detectLangApiUrl + '?key=' + this.apiKey + '&text=' + value)
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the API every time translateText is updated (after each key press). If you don't want to simply have a button, one way to do that would be to listen to the *blur* event (when the user focuses out of the textarea) and call the method then:

```
<template>
    <textarea v-model="translateText" @blur="translate" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Translate something."></textarea>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'TranslateForm',
  data () {
    return {
      translateText: '',
      apiKey: '********',
      detectLangApiUrl: '***********'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    translate () {
       if (this.translateText) {
          axios.post(this.detectLangApiUrl + '?key=' + this.apiKey + '&text=' + this.translateText)
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You could also limit the number of times the method is called, using a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) function. For example, to call translate only once every second:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

export default {
  name: 'TranslateForm',
  data () {
    return {
      translateText: '',
      apiKey: '********',
      detectLangApiUrl: '***********',
      debouncedTranslate: debounce(() => {
        axios.post(this.detectLangApiUrl + '?key=' + this.apiKey + '&text=' + this.translateText)
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
  watch: {
      translateText (value) {
        if (value) {
          this.debouncedTranslate()
        }
      }
   }
}
</script>
```